# ngFor on dynamic FormGroup not updating

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've tried a few different options, and can't seem to get anything working.  I have a series of nested Reactive Forms controls, that are built dynamically, and I'm attempting to render UI elements in response to changes to the Reactive Form being built.

Unfortunately, when I make changes to the Reactive Forms, the UI elements are not updating properly.  It appears that using `*ngFor` on the `controls` property of a `FormGroup` does not update properly when `addControl` is called.

I've created a StackBlitz sample to demonstrate the behavior I'm seeing.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkoxfw

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's NOT `| key` is `| keyvalue`, and use `<input [formControl]="item.value">` to the input,

```
<div [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of form.controls | keyvalue">
    <div>
      {{ item.key }}<input [formControl]="item.value">
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

see your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cgcymy?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I didn't know about `keyvalue` pipe, thanks!  I plugged it into my real use-case, and it's still not working.  I noticed that `keyvalue` pipe is impure, which I did explore, but it crashed the browser tab, so I'll try to update my StackBlitz to pin down why it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining a getter?

Template:

```
div [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="!!form">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let key of controlKeys">
    <div>
      {{ key }}: {{ form.value[key] }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <div>
    <button type="button" (click)="add()">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component:

```
get controlKeys() {
  return Object.keys(this.form.controls);
}
```

Comment: you can use keyvalue pipe too